# Datagrid value does not change

Tags: silverlight

I have a TextBox in CellEditingTemplate in datagird.
When I change its value but it is not reflected to new value.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Firstname}" Grid.Column="1" Width="80"  ></TextBox>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Mode=TwoWay and also use `INotifyPropertyChanged` with Firstname.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Firstname,Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Width="80"/>
```